# Custom REST API - parsing mime mulitpart message

Tags: rest-api, apexrest

I have found this example of how to write a custom REST API to accept binary data.

```
@HttpPut global static String updateCase(RestRequest req) {
    String companyName = req.params.get('companyName');
    Account company = [ Select ID, Name, Type, BillingState from Account where Name =&nbsp;:companyName];

    Attachment a = new Attachment();
    a.ParentId = company.Id;
    a.Name = 'test.png';
    a.Body = req.requestBody;

    insert a;

    return 'Attachment added'; }
```

What I want to do is to accept a MIME/MULTIPART message which may have one or more binary parts.  The use case is to allow attaching multiple attachment to a record with one REST API call.  Is this supported in custom Rest APIs?  I have not been able to find any examples of this.